# jQuery - How to detect scrollLeft AND scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I have the following jQuery code that currently detects if the user scrolls horizontally (`scrollLeft`) past `500px` then fires the included function.

```
jQuery(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if(jQuery(this).scrollLeft() >= 500) {
        mysuperduperfunction();
}});
```

I'd now like for the function to also detect if the user scrolls vertically (`scrollTop`)  past`500px` and fire the same function.

In other words, if the user **either** scrolls left `500px` **or** scrolls down `500px`, I need jQuery to detect this.

Can this be accomplished? How? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use ||

```
jQuery(document).on('scroll', function() {
that = jQuery(this);
    if(that.scrollLeft() >= 500 || that.scrollTop() >= 500) {
        mysuperduperfunction();
}});
```

[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XsgED/)

If this is what you meant I strongly suggest starting here:
[Eloquent javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)